# Jquery JSON DOM not loading data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've been following tutorials trying to get this to work properly--but the data will not display anywhere on my website. For a while it was showing the json_encode return value, but Now its note even displaying that.

```
function currentStarMapURL(URL)
{
        $('#starmap').load(URL, {},
        function()
        {
            $('#loader').hide();
            fullStarInformation(URL);
            starInformation();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'world1.php', error: function () { }, dataType:'json',
            complete: function(data)
            {
                denial = false;
                $('#credits').load(data.credits);
                $('#fuelleft').load(data.fuel);
                $('#energyleft').load(data.energy);
            }
        });
            return false;   
        }
        );
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once("lib/bootstrap.php");

    $money = new userStats($db, $_SESSION['uid']);
    #$upgrades = new upgrades($db, $_SESSION['uid']);
    $credits = $money->balance;
    $energy = $money->energy;
    $fuel = $money->fuel;
    $upgrade = $upgrades->parseXML();
$array = array( 
  'fuel' => $fuel,
  'energy' => $energy, 
  'credits' => $credits, 
  'upgrades' => $upgrade
);
header('Content-type: application/json'); 
return json_encode($array); 

?>
```

Comment: For your `$.ajax` call, use the "success" callback, not "complete".

Comment: @JohnS changed it over, still not getting any output.

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but I think you need to use "echo", not "return". So it would be `echo json_encode($array);`.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you figure out that is the problem

in your js code try this

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log( "success" );
    console.log( data );
  }).fail(function(data) {
    console.log( "fail" );
    console.log( data );

  }).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
    console.log( data );
  });
```

always use your console to check the data if something go wrong

in your php try the follwing

```
echo json_encode($array); 
die();
```

Comment: that JS is returning:
"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'console' of object [object Object] is not a function js.js:49
(anonymous function) js.js:49
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
k jquery.js:8235
r"

Comment: sorry it is console.log() check the edit you can open your console by pressing f12 I suppose you are already know ;)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.load()` accepts a URL from which to load content as an argument.  So, I'm guessing what you need is this:

```
$('#credits').html(data.credits);
$('#fuelleft').html(data.fuel);
$('#energyleft').html(data.energy);
```

where you use `.html()` instead of `.load()`.